# Select data from mysql in faster way

Tags: mysql, select

I had a very large table and I am using query to getting data from this table.
Here is the query.

```
<?php
$input = 'anyword';
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE sentence REGEXP '([^[:alnum:]]|^)$input([^[:alnum:]]|$)'
?>
```

This query work well but here is problem that it is very slow.I need a faster way which work like above query.
Thanks....

Comment: A couple of questions: how wide is your table (i.e. do you need all of the columns returned via *) and has your table been indexed? Otherwise, I would expect a query using regex in this way to be somewhat intensive. The `LIKE` operator should be faster if you can get it to return the same result (very likely).

Comment: @Nathan Unless something changed recently, regexes won't use indexes lookups, best case you'll end up with an index scan instead of a table scan. In other words, indexes on columns you do regex on won't speed things up much. `LIKE` may, as you say, help though :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Nope it hasn't changed, you're correct about it still being a table scan. However, the LIKE clause should be able to benefit from it, if it doesn't start with a wildcard.

Comment: Maybe this post can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740006/mysql-regexp-performance-question

Comment: I know `LIKE` is fast but see this question here is a problem to use of `LIKE` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001848/sql-command-can-not-get-word-related-sentence/16002136?noredirect=1#16002136

Comment: @user2280065 If anything, `REGEXP` is even slower than `LIKE`. Maybe if you describe what you're trying to do on a higher level than matching an exact regexp, there may be an alternate solution to speed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing a regular expression for every row of a large table will be slow. Have a look at [full-text searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) to see how you might use a fulltext index to search for given words in a text column.

Comment: I am using innoDB, So I can not use full text-search

Comment: ok,I can change my database as **MyIsam**.Here is a query `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE MATCH(sentence) AGAINST('anyword', IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.This query is work well. Thanks.....